# How to cancel the shutdown event of PC?

Tags: c#, winforms, systemevent

I am making an application in which i want to execute some database queries just before system get shut down. I am using this code -

```
static void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
{
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Shut down canceled");
}
```

I did execute this application and tried to shut down the system and this code captured the shut down event also but the problem is after showing message box it shows this screen also- [I can't post the image as i don't have 10 points.]

it shows the name of my application that stopped the system to get shut down and it also provide "Force Shut down button" , i dont want this screen to be displayed as user can forcefully shut down the system before completion of execution of my queries.

Need expert advices on this, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can't stop the "force shutdown" screen from appearing (it would have security implications if you could), so why do you need to do it?

Comment: because may be system can get shut down before completion of execution of my query that's why i want to cancel the shut down completely and then want to shut down system using c# or is there any other way i should adopt.

Comment: The "force shutdown" screen waits for user entry anyway, so I'm not understanding the problem?

Comment: What happens if you remove the MessageBox? (You'll still see the Force Shutdown screen, but the sequence of events might differ.)

Comment: but still i am seeing this

Comment: have you tried the shutdown -a?

Comment: @LiranElisha i am not getting you i don't want to shut down the system, i want to stop my system to let it be.

Answer (score 2):

**The Short Reliable Answer:**

On any recent Windows version, you can *try* to cancel shutdown but Windows may decide to ignore you; this is sadly by design. If you absolutely have to finish operations before your process is terminated, the right place to do this is in the SessionEnded handler. If you have tasks that *must* complete before your process terminates, you *must not* return from your SessionEnded handler until all your work is done (so your queries, etc. have finished.)

So instead of (or as well as, if you prefer) handling SessionEnding, handle SessionEnded and do you work there:

```
static void SystemEvents_SessionEnded(object sender, SessionEndedEventArgs e)
{
    WaitForQueriesToFinishOrSaveState(); // new code
}
```

How you implement that waiting will depend on your application; if you need to run queries afresh you may be able to do them therein, or you may need to Thread.Join() or otherwise wait for background tasks to complete; but it must be a blocking wait (so you need to not return from the function until you're done).

Since you *can't* absolutely stop shutdown, there's perhaps little point in attempting the cancellation in this case, so I'd recommend not setting e.Cancel in SessionEnding at all. On older Windows versions this was more meaningful, very much less so now unfortunately.

It's also recommended by [the API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *not* to do any significant work in SessionEnding (including message boxes), but to set any flags you need to return immediately and then do the work in SessionEnded. (Unproven aside: I'm suspicious that if you don't return quickly enough, this may hasten the appearance of the "programs are misbehaving, do you want to kill them" screen for the user, as Windows believes you're not playing nice any more.)

**Behind the Scenes:**

Setting e.Cancel indicates to Windows that you'd *like* the session not to end; but the user still gets a look in; and Windows may decide to ignore your request for any reason it feels pertinent. That's just the way the cookie crumbles. You may find hacks that work situationally, but there's no API or approach which is Microsoft-approved and therefore likely to work consistently now and in the future.

Under the covers, Windows is sending your process' windows a WM_QUERYENDSESSION message, which .NET receives for you and translates into the SessionEnding event) and will pass your cancellation (or lack of) back to Windows; returning TRUE if you don't cancel, FALSE if you do.

After this, Windows takes a look at all process' requests and depending on the cause of the shutdown and other factors may well still decide to go ahead despite such requests. It may also alert the user if processes are not cooperating and give them the option of killing the process.

Whether you handle WM_QUERYENDSESSION (SessionEnding) or not, you always get one last chance to clean up: you're sent a WM_ENDSESSION message (translated into SessionEnded). The tricky part is that you have to do all your vital tasks before all your SessionEnded handlers have returned!

Once Windows hears back from its WM_ENDSESSION (SessionEnded) call, all bets are off as far as your application's lifetime is concerned and Windows can terminate your process at any point.

Raymond Chen covered this quite expertly and quite recently.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/27/10429232.aspx

As a footnote, SystemEvents.SessionEnded is a convenience; if yo have a top level application window you can bypass it entirely and achieve the same via:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x16) // WM_ENDSESSION
    {
        WaitForQueriesToFinishOrSaveState();
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in shutdown command there's a switch for abort shutdown. you have to call this command by your c# code

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        cmd.Start();



        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"shutdown -a");
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: can you explain a bit where should i write this code and how it will work.

Comment: Process.Start("cmd", "shutdown /a");

Comment: @MostafaSoghandi the OP doesn't want to know how to shutdown a computer, he wants to know when the computer is preparing to shutdown and cancel the shutting down to perform some actions then shutdown the computer using his code.

Comment: I know this King King. you can cancel shutdown by -a switch. you can check code ;)

Comment: yep, as i said in the comment before, shutdown -a can be used for this purpose. only you done need all of this messy code